# C# <> Swift Encryption/Decryption

Tags: c#, ios, swift, encryption

I have to send encrypted data from our iOS clients to our C# API. I'm having a hard time getting the same logic to work in both environments. I'm using a test key for this example.

The C# code throws this exception when trying to decrypt it:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The input data is not a complete block.'

I tried comparing the IV in both cases but I haven't had success.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Swift Code

```
import Foundation
import CommonCrypto

public class Encryption {
    private static let hexKey = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12"
    static func encryptString(payload: String) -> String {
        if let privateKey = convertHexStringToData(hexKey){
            let originalPayload = payload
            let iv = generateRandomIV()
            if let encryptedData =  encrypt(originalPayload: originalPayload, privateKey: privateKey,iv: iv){
                let encryptedString = encryptedData.base64EncodedString()
                print("Encrypted payload: \(encryptedString)")
               
                return encryptedString
            }
        }
        
        return ""
    }
    
    private static func encrypt(originalPayload: String, privateKey: Data, iv: Data) -> Data? {
        let bufferSize = originalPayload.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128
        var encryptedData = Data(count: bufferSize)
        
        let status = privateKey.withUnsafeBytes({ privateKeyBytes in
            iv.withUnsafeBytes{ivBytes in
                originalPayload.withCString{ originalPayloadBytes in
                    encryptedData.withUnsafeMutableBytes{ encryptedBytes in
                        CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),
                                CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),
                                CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding),
                                privateKeyBytes.baseAddress,
                                privateKey.count,
                                ivBytes.baseAddress,
                                originalPayloadBytes,
                                originalPayload.count,
                                encryptedBytes.baseAddress,
                                bufferSize,
                                nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        
        guard status == kCCSuccess else{
            print("Encryption failed with status: \(status)")
            return nil
        }
        return encryptedData
    }
    
    private static func convertHexStringToData(_ hexString: String)-> Data?{
        var hex = hexString
        var data = Data()
    
        while !hex.isEmpty{
            let substring = String(hex.prefix(2))
            hex = String(hex.dropFirst(2))
            
            guard let byte = UInt8(substring, radix: 16) else{
                return nil
            }

            data.append(byte)
        }
        
        return data
    }
    
    private static func generateRandomIV() -> Data{
        var iv = Data(count: kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        _ = iv.withUnsafeMutableBytes{ ivBytes in
            SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, kCCBlockSizeAES128, ivBytes.baseAddress!)
        }

        return iv
    }
}
```

Here's the C# code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ScratchPad
{
    static public class Encryption
    {
        private static readonly byte[] CipherKey = ConvertHexStringToByteArray("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12");

        static public string DecryptString(string data)
        {
            return DecryptString(Convert.FromBase64String(data), CipherKey);
        }

        static public T DecryptString<T>(string data)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(DecryptString(Convert.FromBase64String(data), CipherKey));
        }

        static private string DecryptString(byte[] encryptedString, byte[] encryptionKey)
        {
            using (var provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                provider.Key = encryptionKey;
                provider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(encryptedString))
                {
                    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                    ms.Read(iv, 0, 16);
                    var tmp = Convert.ToBase64String(iv);
                    provider.IV = iv;
                    using (var decryptor = provider.CreateDecryptor())
                    {
                        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            using (var sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                            {
                                return sr.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
        {
            if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits: {0}", hexString));
            }

            byte[] HexAsBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
            for (int index = 0; index < HexAsBytes.Length; index++)
            {
                string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2);
                HexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            return HexAsBytes;
        }
    }
}
```